# Objective-C [on OS X Leopard] Garbage Collection, nil Question

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, memory, garbage-collection

I have a question about garbage collection in Objective-C

If I have an object, lets call it 'A'. And 'A' contains instance variables that point to other multiple objects. If I set the pointer to A equaled to nil, will the garbage collector understand that all that is contained in 'A' is also now unused and handle the cleanup? Or do I need to also explicitly make all instance variables in 'A' nil for memory cleanup to occur?

Comment: While there *are* some garbage-collectors for objective-C, that standard method is to use *manual reference counting* [retain/release] as well as some more automated methods like auto-release pools. The exact objective-c run-time should be mentioned (iOS, Leopard, GNU?) in the question for better answers.

Comment: I know of manual memory management, but for this specific project I'm working on I prefer having garbage collection on. The targeted platform is Leopard+.

Comment: On Mac OS X, Objective-C has supported fully automatic garbage collection for a while.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it just works;  the collector knows that a sub-graph of objects, potentially complexly inter-connected, that no longer has any connections from the live objects is garbage.

The collector does full cycle detection, too.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, absolutely, it will work.

HOWEVER, note that garbage collection is non-deterministic, that is, there's no telling when it will run.

Therefore, any destructors you need called won't be called immediately when you nil the pointer.

If the object 'A' is, or holds references to, file objects, database objects, connection objects, etc. then you will need to use reference counting to ensure that these are freed immediately.

Otherwise, use GC; it's a lot less painful.